# How to edit 'column select' shortcut in Sublime text 3 portable

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, multiple-columns, sublimetext

I am a novice to Sublime text. Previously I used notepad++. I use column selection frequently. In notepad++ it comes to me handy with `alt` + `left mouse click` which I can drag up to my wished selection.

In Sublime text, it is `shift` + `right mouse click` and drag up to wished selection for Windows. I want to change it to `alt` + `left mouse click` as I have used it in notepad++.
I tried searching in `preferences > key bindings` in sublime text. But couldn't find mouse-key mappings there. I am using **portable version of Sublime text 3** on **Windows**.

Comment: Is there any wrong with my question? or suggest me link to solve my problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to `Preferences > Browse Packages...` then create a new file called `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` in the `User` folder.

Insert the following:

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns"}
    },
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["alt", "ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns", "additive": true}
    },
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["shift", "alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns", "subtractive": true}
    },
]
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot @Mr.F. I couldn't upvote due to insufficient reputation.

Comment: @kvchivukula Glad I could help

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! You just upvoted me to 666!