# Changing the mouse button and modifier key used for column selection in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

To select a column in Sublime Text (on Windows) you use `Shift+Right Click`.

[image]

How can I change the mouse button and modifier key to `Alt+Left Click` so it is the same as *Notepad++*?

I found a similar question/answer [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505914/how-to-edit-column-select-shortcut-in-sublime-text-3-portable) but it did not work.

Here is my `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` file but nothing happens when I press `Alt+Left-Click` or `Alt+Right-Click`.

```json
[
    {
      "keys": ["ctrl+s"], "command": "run_multiple_commands", "args": {"commands": [ {"command": "save"}, {"command": "create_backup_copy" } ] }
    },

      // toggle fold all
    {
      "keys": ["f12"], "command": "fold_all"
    },

      //toggle fold current code block
    {
        "keys": ["f11"], "command": "toggle_fold_current"
    },

    //alt+ left click column select
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["shift"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns"}
    },

    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["shift", "ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns", "additive": true}
    },

    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["shift", "alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns", "subtractive": true}
    },

    //re-open recent file
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+t"], "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index" : 0}
    },
]
```

Comment: You didn't change the code under `//alt+ left click column select` in your `.sublime-mousemap` to match the code you listed earlier. The modifiers should be, in order, `alt`, `alt, ctrl`, and `shift, alt` instead of `shift`, `shift, ctrl`, and `shift, alt`.

Comment: Not quite @MattDMo. The sequence you (somewhat cryptically) describe is correct, but Caio's code is a mixture of mouse bindings and key bindings which clearly shouldn't be in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` is a very strange looking `sublime-mousemap`. It should not contain any key bindings at all but for some reason it contains key bindings to call the `run_multiple_commands`, `fold_all`, `toggle_fold_current`, and `open_recent_file` commands.

Those key bindings should be in `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` and not in `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap`.

I think you might have added the `Alt+Left Click` code to your user `sublime-keymap` file instead of a user `sublime-mousemap` file and you didn't change the modifier key from `Shift` to `Alt`.

The StackOverflow code that [you found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508209/2102457) looks correct to me. I have posted it again below. Copy and paste it into a new file and save it in your Sublime Text config `User` directory as `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap`. On Windows that path should be as I've shown below, or something like that, the directory should be the same one as your user key bindings file is in:

```
%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap
```

Copy and paste this code (credit: Mr.F):

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns"}
    },
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["alt", "ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns", "additive": true}
    },
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["shift", "alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns", "subtractive": true}
    },
]
```

If that works for you then make sure you upvote the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508209/2102457) as well as this one. I nearly marked your question for closing as a duplicate - I didn't because you are clearly confused by the different config files, and I couldn't provide the explanation within the space constraints of a comment.